# Using host environmental variables in docker-compose that are passed to DockerFile while using vscode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to use wget inside my DockerFile to download a file that requires a password to do so, so in docker-compose.yml I tried to add to args a variable that reads a variable from host and passes it to DockerFile but i cannot figure out what i am doing wrong in here.
The whole thing is run inside visual code studio

Inside devcontainer.json

```
...
"containerEnv": {
    "${localEnv:PRIVATE_TOKEN}"
},
"remoteEnv": {
    "${localEnv:PRIVATE_TOKEN}"
},
...
```

inside .bashrc:

```
...
MY_PASSWORD='123'
```

inside Docker-Compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  my_service:
    image: ...
    build:
      ...
      args:
        MY_PASSWORD: ${MY_PASSWORD}
    ...
```

inside Dockerfile:

```
ARG MY_PASSWORD
RUN wget --progress=dot:giga -O my_file.tgz remot_link_to_my_file --header "MY_PASSWORD: $MY_PASSWORD"
```

when inside Docker-compose i change `${MY_PASSWORD}` to real value it does work.

Comment: are you using wsl(2) and vscode? Also you mix up array and object syntax.

Comment: i am using vscode on archlinux,
could you elaborate on that part mix up?

Comment: see the below answer. Thats yaml object syntax. There is no equal sign.

Comment: If you use vscode + wsl 2 then the bashrc is not sourced in devcontainer. You need to put it in .profile.

Comment: I don't use the WSL, just vscode and good catch with the syntax, it was only here not in my real code :)

Answer (score 0):

Your args configuration is wrong or old. This works as expected:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        MY_PASSWORD: ${MY_PASSWORD}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
from ubuntu
ARG MY_PASSWORD
RUN mkdir /tmp/$MY_PASSWORD
RUN ls -la /tmp
```

Arg is passed and used to create folder:

[image]